# Semantic UI dropdown icon only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

Based on http://jsfiddle.net/t9vfxo5t/ I want a Semantic UI dropdown as shown but the final result I only want to be displayed as the flag, not the flag and country name text. I still want the country names to appear on the drop down when clicked though.

I tried removing the text in http://jsfiddle.net/Lhzua273/1/ but it then also removes it from the dropdown list.

```
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
    <input type="hidden" name="language">
    <div class="default text">Select language</div>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="item" data-value="gb"><i class="gb flag"></i>English</div>
        <div class="item" data-value="es"><i class="es flag"></i></div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone suggest how it could be achieved?

(Ultimately it is so I can have 4 icon dropdowns side by side horizontally in a div row as shown so they fit across a mobile phone in portrait mode. It's so the user can select preferred country 1, 2, 3 and 4. I'm also hoping when each list drops down after clicking, they can still fit inside the portrait screen, so the left margin of the dropdown list would need to go negative if the list was hitting the right edge of the screen.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You want something like this?

```
    <div class="ui compact selection dropdown">
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            <div class="text">FLAG</div>
            <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item"><i class="es flag"></i></div>
                    <div class="item"><i class="jp flag"></i></div>
                    <div class="item"><i class="ru flag"></i></div>
                    <div class="item"><i class="cn flag"></i></div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/busLpjag/

This is bad UX, better to use modal with country selection list.

5 (or more) flags in dropdown = scrollbar inside your dropdown :(

Comment: Thanks but we also wanted the country names to appear next to the flags when the list was dropped down.

Comment: Also we plan to loose the dropdown arrow too.

Comment: And thanks for the comment re modal. We actually only have a total of 7 countries to choose from. Not sure whether that would be OK?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `data-text` in each `.menu .item` element.

Ie:

```
<div class="item" data-text="Spanish" data-value="es">
  <i class="es flag"></i>
</div>
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9t5qapog/2/

I've also included the flag icon inside the `data-text` of each option on the JSFiddle. This is not mandatory.

Comment: Thanks but we actually wanted it the other way round --so that only the flag appears after the drop down is down but the country names still appear in the drop down list.